# JWT::InvalidIssuerError: Invalid issuer. Expected accounts.google.com, received https://accounts.google.com

Tags: google-oauth

My website didn't have a problem in the past for login using Google oauth. Suddenly I am getting the above error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to downgrade your `omniauth-google-oauth2` version. You can simply add `verify_iss: false` to your `config.omniauth`.

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, 
                Rails.application.secrets.oauth_google_id, 
                Rails.application.secrets.oauth_google_secret, 
                verify_iss: false
```

For more info, look at the `verify_iss` in https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2#configuration

Comment: https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2 reads: "`verify_iss`: Allows you to disable iss validation when decoding the JWT. This was added since Google now returns either `accounts.google.com` or `https://accounts.google.com`, and there is no way to predict what they will return, causing JWT validation failures."

Comment: It looks like `verify_iss` Has been removed as of 0.5.4 https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/compare/v0.5.4...master

Comment: Looks like this has been fixed in 0.6.0 https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/issues/348

Answer (score 1):

I got same issue on RoR with  "omniauth-google-oauth2 - 0.5.1". I have to user old version (0.5.0) and it's working fine. I think google has changed behavior on authentication process.